# GemNotFoundException when using Ruby on Rails after installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation

I am trying to install Ruby on Rails on my Windows PC. I used RailsInstaller to install it. When I type any commands involving "rails," it gives me this error message. My Ruby version is up to date.

```
C:\Users\caleb>ruby -v
ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users\caleb>rails -v
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.3/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
        1: from C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:262:in `bin_path'
C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `find_spec_for_exe': can't find gem railties (>= 0.a) with executable rails (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
```

I tried installing it again with "gem install rails," but that doesn't work. Maybe it's because RailsInstaller already installed it:

```
C:\Users\caleb>gem install rails
Temporarily enhancing PATH for MSYS/MINGW...
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.2/ext/nio4r
C:/tools/ruby26/bin/ruby.exe -I C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/2.6.0 -r ./siteconf20200717-3196-rctiq0.rb extconf.rb

current directory: C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.2/ext/nio4r
make "DESTDIR=" clean
current directory: C:/tools/ruby26/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/nio4r-2.5.2/ext/nio4r
make "DESTDIR="
make failedNo such file or directory - make "DESTDIR="
```

I've looked at other similar questions on StackOverflow where people got this error message, and none of the solutions worked for me. Some of them suggested using RVM, but that's apparently not available on Windows.

Comment: If you read the error message, you can see your machine is confused about which version of ruby is currently running. On one line it talks about ruby `2.6.6`, then on the next line it says ruby `2.3.3`.

Comment: If you only care about having one version of ruby on the machine, then you should ensure *all traces* of the other version(s) are completely gone. Or, if you would like to switch between versions then it's advisable to let a version manager handle this for you - such as `rvm` or `rbenv` or `chruby`. (And yes, `rvm` *is* available on Windows - where did you read that it isn't? The [website](https://rvm.io/rvm/install) says that it is.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deleted the folder with Ruby 2.3.3 in it, which I'd gotten from RailsInstaller, and reinstalled Ruby 2.6.6 with RubyInstaller. Then I did "gem install rails" again, and it worked.